# XCode don't want to run App on Device

Tags: xcode

I click the button Run and XCode refuse to run.

[image]

My question is: How to fix? This happens a lot of times. Only way to solve for me is to restart XCode. Then after a while, it happens again. And again. And again. Please help how to fix.

Comment: Is your Xcode the latest version? Did you try to re-install Xcode? Does this issue happen in all projects?

Comment: @Raptor yep latest version.

Comment: @matt "refuse to run" means Xcode don't even start building (no activity). Did u see the gif i put up there? See how I click on Run button and nothing happens? Normally when Run is clicked, then the Stop button becomes black and the app starts on the device.

Answer (score 2):

you have to solve this using with the Manage Schemes dialog. Follow the below path...

- Go to:Choose Product > Scheme > Manage Schemes.
- Choose Manage Schemes from the scheme toolbar menu.
- Click Manage Schemes at the bottom of the scheme editing sheet.

if there are no any scheme available then Click **Autocreate Scheme** either any schemes available then remove all and **Autocreate Scheme Now**
[image]

Comment: I tried this when the problem happens. It doesnt solve it. I have found out yesterday that after I click Run -> (nothing happens), then I change device selected to simulator, and then change back to iphone, then the app will run. pretty sure this is a bug on xcode.

Comment: @Rocotilos yes its bug of Xcode and many time our App scheme is not show then we have to manage and referesh new schemes